# autocomplete with inline suggestion in textarea

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

for my project i have a textarea

```
<textarea class="FormControl Composer-flexible TextEditor-editor" placeholder="message..." style="height: 189px;"></textarea>
```

and i'm here to ask if there's a way to autocomplete with suggestion INSIDE textarea itself. for example if i start to write "Here" i want to see the suggestion "here comes the suggestion" and if i press maybe a TAB key or something else i can select the suggestion.

there's a way to do that with plain javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```js
const suggestions = [
                      "Here comes the suggestions", 
                      "I like pizza", 
                      "I'm a good programmer"
                    ]

var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  var result = suggestions.filter(el => el.startsWith(textarea.value))
  console.log(result)
})
```

```html
    <textarea class="FormControl Composer-flexible TextEditor-editor" id="textarea" placeholder="message..." style="height: 189px;"></textarea>
```

Put result inside a box.

Comment: yes like this, but how can i put che result into a box INSIDE the textarea?

Comment: You can try to put the suggestions a div and use css to move it inside the textarea, or you can put the text directly in textarea box using result.forEach(suggestions => {textarea.value += suggestions} but II think it's not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Note my code is case sensitive

```js
const texts = ["Here comes the suggestion", "Another suggestion"]

document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  console.log(e.key, e.target.value)
  if (e.key === "Tab") {
    const val = this.value;
    texts.forEach(text => {
      if (text.startsWith(val)) this.value = text;
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="editor" class="FormControl Composer-flexible TextEditor-editor" placeholder="message..." style="height: 189px;"></textarea>
```